# TypeError due to float() argument when I create a network with nodes colored using a colormap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, networkx

I have the following two datasets

```
Node     Edge
A         B
A         D
B         N
B         A
B         X
S         C
```

and

```
Nodes    Attribute
A           -9
B           
C           -1.5
D           1.0
...
N           1.0
... 
X           0.0
Y           -1.5
W          -1.5
Z           1.0
```

where Attribute type is float64. For replication, you can use the following (unique Attribute elements, i.e., uni_val): `array([ 9. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0.5, -0.5, -1. , -1.5, -2. ])`

I want to create a network using a color map for coloring nodes. I did as follows:

```
# Create map of color

uni_val=df2.Attribute.unique()
colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,len(df2.Attribute.unique())))

n=0
val=[]
col=[]

for i in uni_val:
    val.append(i)
    col.append(colors[n])
    n=n+1

mapper=dict(zip(val,col))
colour_map = df2.set_index('Nodes')['Attribute'].map(mapper)

# Create the network

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1, source='Node', target='Edge')
# Add Attribute to each node
nx.set_node_attributes(G, colour_map, name="colour")

# Then draw with colours based on attribute values:
nx.draw(G, 
        node_color=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'colour').values(),
        with_labels=True)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict_values'
```

but I do not understand what is causing it and how I can fix it.
It would be great if you could help me to better understand it and show me a way to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current mapping is incorrect. A valid colour code format is needed not arrays:

From the docs [networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html)

> Node color. Can be a single color or a sequence of colors with the same length as nodelist. Color can be string or rgb (or rgba) tuple of floats from 0-1. If numeric values are specified they will be mapped to colors using the cmap and vmin,vmax parameters.

The following mapping is created with the current approach:

```
uni_val = np.array([9., 0., 1., 0.5, -0.5, -1., -1.5, -2.])
colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0, 1, len(uni_val)))

print(colors)
n = 0
val = []
col = []

for i in uni_val:
    val.append(i)
    col.append(colors[n])
    n = n + 1

mapper = dict(zip(val, col))
```

`mapper`:

```
{-2.0: array([0.5, 0. , 0. , 1. ]),
 -1.5: array([1.        , 0.18954248, 0.        , 1.        ]),
 -1.0: array([1.        , 0.72694263, 0.        , 1.        ]),
 -0.5: array([0.71790006, 1.        , 0.24984187, 1.        ]),
 0.0: array([0.        , 0.06470588, 1.        , 1.        ]),
 0.5: array([0.24984187, 1.        , 0.71790006, 1.        ]),
 1.0: array([0.        , 0.64509804, 1.        , 1.        ]),
 9.0: array([0. , 0. , 0.5, 1. ])}
```

These arrays are invalid inputs for colours.

---

These arrays need to be converted into some valid form. A simple fix would be to use [matplotlib.colors.to_hex](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.to_hex.html#matplotlib.colors.to_hex)

```
uni_val = np.array([9., 0., 1., 0.5, -0.5, -1., -1.5, -2.])
colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0, 1, len(uni_val)))
mapper = dict(zip(uni_val, map(mcolor.to_hex, colors)))
```

Which produces:

```
{-2.0: '#800000',
 -1.5: '#ff3000',
 -1.0: '#ffb900',
 -0.5: '#b7ff40',
 0.0: '#0010ff',
 0.5: '#40ffb7',
 1.0: '#00a4ff',
 9.0: '#000080'}
```

---

All together it can look like:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, colors as mcolor

# Sample DataFrames
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Node': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'S'],
    'Edge': ['B', 'D', 'N', 'A', 'X', 'C']
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Nodes': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'N', 'S', 'X'],
    'Attribute': [-1, 0, -1.5, 1, 1, 9, 0]
})

# Simplified construction of `colour_map`
uni_val = df2['Attribute'].unique()
colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0, 1, len(uni_val)))
# Map colours to_hex then zip with
mapper = dict(zip(uni_val, map(mcolor.to_hex, colors)))
colour_map = df2.set_index('Nodes')['Attribute'].map(mapper)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1, source='Node', target='Edge')
# Add Attribute to each node
nx.set_node_attributes(G, colour_map, name="colour")

# Then draw with colours based on attribute values:
nx.draw(G,
        node_color=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'colour').values(),
        with_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

Producing a graph like:

[image: coloured graph]

Comment: Thank you so much Henry (I would like also to thank patizos for the previous answer). I am getting this error with my whole dataset: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict_values'` caused by `----> 6 nx.draw(G,node_color=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'colour').values(),with_labels=True)` . Do you have any idea on what is causing it?

Comment: I would guess that somewhere you have an incomplete mapping. So for example, if you have a node in `df1` that does _not_ appear in `df2` you'll end up with a `NaN` value after you map to attributes. `NaN` is technically a float value. You could print `colour_map` to make sure that you do not have any NaN values in the column.

Comment: it makes sense. So there is no way to handle with NaN values in case some values is missing in my df (e.g., setting a default color value for nan), right? In df2 there should be all the values from df1 from both Node and Edge columns. It is weird...

Comment: [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) => `colour_map = df2.set_index('Nodes')['Attribute'].map(mapper).fillna('some default colour')` can be used to fill NaN with some default.

Comment: Thanks @HenryEcker for clarifying my error and for providing the correct answer. I deleted mine as it was not only wrong but could be misleading to future readers.

Comment: I don't know that I have any more ideas with the information I currently have sorry @LdM

Comment: @pazitos10 no worries. I find the networkx docs unclear generally particularly about the input formats.